# Visual Studio C++ Cannot load Symbols and access violation when debugging

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, access-violation

I am having a very strange issue. I have a c++ project that was working just fine until today. Today I tried to run the visual studio debugger and at the very beginning of the main function, I get an access violation exception. The line where the exception occurs varies, though it is always in the first few lines of my main function. Visual studio claims the source file is not available.

I'm not sure what changed, although recently, upon opening the visual studio project, I was presented with a message about finding a suitable location for he pdb, which i naively clicked "ok" to.

In case this helps, the call stack is:

```
ntdll.dll!_RtlInitUnicodeStringEx@8()
KernelBase.dll!LoadLibraryExW() 
KernelBase.dll!_LoadLibraryW@4()    
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()    
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()
```

Edit:

I tried a new empty project. Literally:

```
// TestProj.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"


int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

and I get a similar error.

Comment: clear/rebuild is your friend

Comment: Already tried. did not work.

Comment: actually if its an access violation issue, the problem seems to be something more serious. from my experience, sometimes i end up editing a library file by accident and this is when I usually end up with a symbol not found issues. it could be related to that.

Comment: It seems my configuration is set up as x86 (on a windows 10 x64 machine). This was not breaking anything before, but I figured I'd mention it

Comment: In the empty project it tells me ntdll.pdb is not loaded. Not quite sure what that means or what to do about it.

Comment: .pdb are debug symbol files, they are not related to access violation (also VS typically automatically finds pdb files). Also which library is being loaded at that stack trace?

Comment: In the empty project, the stack trace is:

`ntdll.dll!RtlInitUnicodeStringEx() 
 KernelBase.dll!00007ffc0eb4294b()
 kernel32.dll!00007ffc119a3034() 
 ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart() `

not even loading a library. I'm not sure which library is loading in my other project. How can I find out?

Comment: I'm trying to uninstall and reinstall visual studio at this point. Seems to be a VS problem if i can't debug an empty project

Comment: SOLUTION: Reinstall Visual Studio. Sigh. I don't want to post as an answer as it does not really explain anything, but it did solve my problem.